# How to correctly map & update a self referencing entity with fluent-nhibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to create an entity which currently owns a List of the same entity, this link exists in another table.

This is then exposed as an API.
I'm able to fetch data, but everytime I try to update the collection, it results in an error : `a collection with cascade= all-delete-orphan was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance`

```cs
public class MyEntity
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ISet<MyEntity> LinkedEntities { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using fluent nhibernate automapping, and so, overriding the default mapping.

```cs
var fluentConfigurationCampaign = Fluently.Configure()
.CurrentSessionContext("mySession")
.Database(
          MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(MyConnectionString)
        )
        .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<MyEntity>(cfg)
.Conventions.Setup(c => c.Add<CustomForeignKeyConvention>())
.Override<MyEntity>(map => map.HasManyToMany(i => i.LinkedEntities)
.ParentKeyColumn("EntitySelf")
.ChildKeyColumn("EntityOther")
.Table("Linked").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan())
```

The linked table, as suggested by the mapping contains only 3 properties.

A self generated ID

A foreignKey EntitySelf linking to the Entity table

A foreignKey EntityOther linking to the Entity table.

When updating an entity (through a controller), I'm getting an EntityContract which is mapped through automapper to an Entity.

I then do :

```cs
_session.Merge(myEntityFromController);
var oldEntity = _session.Get<T>(myEntityFromController.Id);
_session.Update(oldEntity);
_session.Flush();
```

Which is working fine for all my other entities.
But, trying to change the List of LinkedEntities (either by removing some, or adding, or even not touching it), I got the error : `a collection with cascade= all-delete-orphan was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance`

Any help would be appreciated as I'm stuck on this issue !
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my issue was related to the `.Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()` part of the mapping.
I thought it would reference to my `Linked` table, but instead, it seems it was trying to act on the `MyEntity` linked, hence producing my error.

Removing it made everything works with no other tweak needed.